# an inequality over integers

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be integers different from 1.
Prove that if $x+y\leq xy$ and $y+z \leq yz$ then $x+z\leq xz$
My attempt:
$x+2y+z\leq (x+z)y$   $~~$so $2y \leq (x+z)(y-1)$
and I'm stack here.
I need just some hint.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that there are counterexamples in the real numbers (for example, $x=z=\frac32$ and $y=3$), so something about the integers has to be used. Hint: $x+y\le xy$ if and only if $1\le xy-x-y+1 = (x-1)(y-1)$. The restriction that $x,y,z\ne1$ seens unnecessary.

Comment: Are the integers positive?

Comment: $x~,~y~ ,~z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\left\{\begin{aligned} & x+y \leqslant xy \\& y+z \leqslant yz \end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{aligned} & (x-1)(y-1) \geqslant 1\\& (y-1)(z-1) \geqslant 1\end{aligned}\right. \Rightarrow (x-1)(z-1)(y-1)^2 \geqslant 1 > 0.$$
Therefore
$$ (x-1)(z-1) > 0 $$
But $x,\,y,\,z$ are integers, so
$$(x-1)(z-1) \geqslant 1 \Rightarrow x+z \leqslant xz.$$
Done.

Comment: thank you sir for your help